# NSPredicate for a boolean

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I've got a boolean attr on an entity and the generated code for it is:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * countdownMode;
@dynamic countdownMode;
```

The entity is saved with:

```
score.countdownMode = @(YES);
```

The fetchRequest has the following predicate:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"countdownMode == YES"];
```

For some reason, the fetch never returns anything.. Any ideas? When the predicate is removed, the rows are fetched. In the debugger I can see that the countdownMode is 1. I've also tried these with no success:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"countdownMode == %@", @YES];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"countdownMode == %d", YES];
```

This seems like it should be simple but its not returning any results. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you try change NSNumber to NSInteger or int16_t and see if the comparission on predicate works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**All** these are completely equivalent.

```
@"count = 1"
@"count = true"
@"count = YES"
@"count = %@", @YES
@"count = %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
// plus all these versions with "=="
```

None of these is preferable, except for reasons of brevity and clarity. The resulting call to the SQLite data base will be exactly the same, so there is absolutely no difference in effect, safety or performance.

Take a look, the SQLite database is storing "1". (This is an implementation detail that could change, so do not rely on it. For all practical purposes, though, it does not matter).

Also, `@YES` and `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]` are exactly the same. The former is a new form of literal notation introduced with "Modern Objective C".

It follows, that the reason for no records must be a different one. Check if your managed object context is not `nil`; if there is not another predicate limiting the results; if you are displaying a different result from the one you think you have fetched; if you have not changed the data inadvertently before performing the fetch; if you have forgotten to call `save` at the right place, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean value are not recommended to explicitly comparing with YES. Thus try this case:

```
BOOL yes = YES;
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"countDownMode == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:yes]];
```

Comment: isn't this is the same as `@YES`?

Comment: No, it's an instance of class NSNumber which also used by NSManagedObject for handling numbers and boolean inclusive. I'm not assure completely but I advice you to try it.

Comment: Pretty sure they are the same, the OP has already tried it: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#nsnumber-literals

Comment: OK, try this one: `[[NSNumber numberWithBool: YES] description]`

Comment: @YES is just literal syntax for [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], they are identical - NSNumber pointers. YES is a scalar of type BOOL. [[NSNumber numberWithBool: YES] description] is a string. `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"countDownMode == %@", @YES];` is valid predicate syntax, presuming `countDownMode` is a boolean.